# check query for value exist

Tags: android, sqlite

how can check if some value is available in a column in the table or not i used this way but  the application crash when the value is not in the table

```
Cursor r = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE3,
                    new String[] { "_id", "point_name", "No_of_visits" }, 
                    "point_langtitude" + "=" + lang + " and " + "point_latitude"
                    + "=" + lat,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);

if(r == null)
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  r.moveToFirst();
  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
  args.put("No_of_visits", 7);
  boolean d = db.update(DATABASE_TABLE3,
                        args,
                        "_id" + "=" + r.getInt(0),
                        null) > 0;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output please.

Comment: 06-03 11:43:27.820: ERROR/Database(490): Error inserting points_counter=1 point_langtitude=-10084093 _id=26 point_latitude=37422005
06-03 11:43:27.820: ERROR/Database(490): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: please any help I need this in my graduation project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(r != null && r.moveToFirst()) {
    // Update
    r.close();
} else {
    // Do not call r.close() here because r is null
}
```

Comment: I updated the awnser, the problem in your code is that you called r.close() when r is null.

Comment: okay, but even when i remove r.close the problem will still appear

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully:

```
if(r == null)
{
  // r is null
  r.close(); // what now ... ?
  return true;
}
```

And use a debugger before asking questions :)